# 'active' navigation item depends on certain section

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I'm using plugin Scrollify for my landing, all is great, but I can't solve one problem. I have 8 sections, which of them has a different "data-section-name" attribute. 
Also I have the navigation, it looks like circles with 'active' class. I wrote function, so now when I click on any circle, it becomes 'active' and scroll to certain section. But when I use scroll by mouse, circles' 'active' doesnt' change. What should I do? How can I identify section and do 'active' certain cirlcle?

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can have a look?

Comment: Scrollify js does not support navigation by default. You are suppose to write your own script for implementing scroll navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the active section's data by using `$.scrollify.current()` method on `before()` or `after()` your `scrollify()` property. By matching your data, you can add active class to your navigation.

Find below [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/r2ss0a5k/2/) for your reference.

Here I used a fixed-nav on left for scroll navigation indication(not captures click event). Hope it helps.